# Preserving Function Pointer Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, function-pointers, using

Typically I'll preserve function arguments something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
    using type = T;
};
```

I know it's not going to be `using` but in what way can I preserve a function passed as a template parameter?

```
template<void (*T)(const int)>
struct bar {
    static T& type = T;
};
```

I know this doesn't work, I just want to know how I can go about the act of preserving this function pointer.

Comment: When you say preserve, do you mean rename?  `T` will already preserve the pointer, since it is the pointer.

Comment: In the first example, `T` refers to a type. In the second example, it refers to a value. The code that doesn't work tries to use the value as a type. That doesn't work with or without templates. BTW: You could replace the function pointer with e.g. an integer as template parameter, which is also a value and not a type. BTW2: `T` is `ALL_UPPERCASE` and thus suggests a macro, which is probably not what you intend.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm sorry, I mean preserve for future external access.

Comment: @JonathanMee Do you want to expose the type or the value? Or both?

Comment: @NathanOliver just the value. The type is already specified. Plus I suppose I could use `decletype` to get it from the value anyway, if I needed that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `decltype` to declare a member variable of the type of `T` that people can refer to like

```
template<void (*T)(const int)>
struct bar {
    static constexpr decltype(T) value = T;
};
```

You can take it a step farther and make the type of `T` a member as well like

```
template<void (*T)(const int)>
struct bar {
    using fptr = decltype(T)
    static constexpr fptr value = T;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

When used like this:

```
template<void (*T)(const int)>
struct bar {
    static T& type = T;
};
```

T is a non-type template parameter, and there is no type to preserve (I would also suggest a different name for it, since T usually refers to type)

You can make a pointer itself available as a member of the struct, for example

```
static constexpr int (*func_ptr)(int) = T;
```